# How to Convert Custom string to ptime using boost

Tags: c++11, boost

I have a string "2018Jan23T181138.65498648" which I need to convert to ptime. I have used below code but seems it is not working. Any idea what I am doing wrong here.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime   pt;

std::istringstream is("2018Jan23T181138.65498648");
is.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%f")));
is >> pt;
std::cout << pt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least match the format string to reflect the input format.

"Jan" is not a valid match for `%Y%m%d` (which would expect `20180123` instead). Likewise, `%S.%f` is a format string that might work for formatting¹, but to parse the seconds with fractions, [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags) show to use `%s`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbb430f87dceeac5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::posix_time::ptime   pt;

    std::istringstream is("2018Jan23T181138.65498648");
    is.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%Y%b%dT%H%M%s")));
    if (is >> pt) {
        std::cout << pt << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "unparsed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
2018-Jan-23 18:11:38.654986
```

---

¹ haven't tested it for output formatting

Comment: Thanks for the solution. have already done it this way and is working fine :)

Comment: Cheers, and [Welcome to SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)